# Dataframe to CSV with cell value as list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a pandas dataframe as so

```
data = {'name': ['alice', 'bob'], 'lucky_numbers': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Is there a way to covert this dict to a csv like so,

```
name,lucky_numbers
alice,1
,2
bob,3
,4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name': ['alice', 'bob'], 'lucky_numbers': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).explode('lucky_numbers').to_csv('lucky_numbers.csv', index=False)
```

or, if you want exactly that:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name': ['alice', 'bob'], 'lucky_numbers': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).explode('lucky_numbers').reset_index(drop=True)
df.loc[~df.index.isin(df.groupby('name').head(1).index), 'name'] = ""
df.to_csv("lucky_numbers.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the `luck_numbers` as a list will be as simples as data:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ['alice', 'bob'], 'lucky_numbers': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.to_csv('your_file_name.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

#### Output

```
name,lucky_numbers
alice,"[1, 2]"
bob,"[3, 4]"
```